# How does ActiveMQ assign the slowConsumer designation?

Tags: activemq-classic

In the JMX console for ActiveMQ there is a SlowConsumer attribute displayed for consumers.  I have seen some mention of it in documentation, but nothing that explains how this is set/determined.

I have actually seen some consumers marked as slow which appear to move faster than those with SlowConsumer = false.

[This page](http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumers.html) explains some of the ramifications of the designation, but not how the designation is made.